# Error: 'Default Activity Not Found' for an app containing a Broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-broadcastreceiver

I have two *separate* apps.

The first sends out two different kinds of Broadcasts.

The second one waits for this broadcast from App #1 and uses the broadcast to decide what activity to launch.

What I'm confused about is this: It seems to me that App #2 (the receiving app) shouldn't necessarily require a default activity since the activity it launches depends on the broadcast received from App #1.

But, if a default activity is not defined in App #2, it can't run and throws:

> Error running app: Default activity not found

But, if I do define one in the manifest file, then this defeats the purpose of the Broadcast.

Please help me understand the bigger picture and maybe offer a solution.

**UPDATE**: The issue is solved. To the people facing the same problem, I found 2 possible ways to resolve this:

- As suggested by @Lemi Miles, We can simply go to App>edit 
  Configurations> On launch options and choose Launch "Nothing".
- Alternatively, you could create an activity with no functionality to 
  act as a launcher activity for the app

Comment: simply define a default Activity and use this Activity as proxy for the other two.

Comment: Post your manifest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App>edit Configurations>
On launch options choose Launch "Nothing"

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem since 3 days.. If you are sure that there is no problem in your manifest.xml then Here is a solution... 
1)Delete Android.3.1 or which version folder you have from c/User/Android.your version... 
2)Then start Android again..

It worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try this: In Android Studio Tool Bar -> select Run->Edit Configuration-> On Launch Option ->Select Nothing in place of Default Activity

Comment: Hi, just a note for future contributions. This question already had an accepted answer. Your answer looks very similar to that one. Consider adding more value next time.