# android studio 3.2 default activity not found

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-studio-3.2

Recently I updated my android studio to 3.2 but when the old open project I getting the error **"default activity not found"**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.qualifiedapps.birthdaywishes">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Did you try to re-import your project?

Also, you can delete .gradle and .idea folders in your root folder.

Comment: Test case **`Clear-Rebuild-run`** or just use **`invalidate-cache- and restart-studio`**

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found

Comment: yes i did, and also tried **invalidate caches /  Restart**

Comment: Try to add this line to your <application> `android:name=".app"`

Comment: I tried but still getting this error  ** Default Activity not found **.

Comment: specify like full path <activity android:name="com.qualifiedapps.birthdaywishes.MainActivity">

Comment: It's not working adding the full path

Comment: can u show ur app structure

Comment: java > com > qualifiedapps  > birthdaywishes > MainActivity

Comment: [This worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49656716/6648201) hope it saves others time as well.

Answer (score 25):

None of the given solutions worked for me. The thing that worked for me was:

- Exit Android Studio
- Find AndroidStudio3.2 (or whatever your version is) folder
- Go to AndroidStudio3.2 -> system -> caches
- Delete that folder
- Restart Android Studio

It will re-index your files and that thing will work

Comment: really helpful, I was stuck on it for 2 days..thanks

Comment: There is no **-> system -> caches** directory

Answer (score 3):

I solved the very same issue by doing this

Close Android Studio

deleting :

1 .android

2 .AndroidStudio

3 .gradle

from C:\Users\[your user name]

Start Android studio ( Will take some time to rebuild)

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me by adding the default activity in the configuration, Following these steps:

1- Select Edit Configurations from the drop down next to run button.

2- Under launch options > Launch select Specified activity.

3- Another field "Activity" will appear select your default activity.

4- Click OK and sync project with gradle files and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you refactored it in anyway ? Trying doing :

1. Cleaned the Project
2. Deleted the Build directory
3. Restarted Android Studio
4. Rebuild the Project
5. Run

Answer (score 1):

I deleted .android under C:\Users[your user name] and all worked

Answer (score 0):

I solved the very same issue by following steps

Close Android Studio

deleting from :

1. C:\Users\your user name.android/log and gradle folder
2. C:\Users\your user name.gradle

from C:\Users[your user name]

Restart Computer and run Android studio (it Will take some time to rebuild)

Answer (score 0):

All I did was disable offline mode and sync project

Answer (score 0):

For future visitors with similar problem, I am just posting this incase if this turns out to be same problem for you. I tried everything mentioned here and yet none of them worked.
[Error: Default Activity Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15825081/error-default-activity-not-found)

I am using Android Studio Stable 3.2.1 version and project is in Kotlin.
I cloned project again and opened project freshly again after several Invalidate caches/Restart but din't help. 
Finally this 1 helped -> upgrading **kotlin version** in **root .gradle** file..from **1.3.10 to 1.3.11**

In root gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    ext.annotation_version = "27.1.1"
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

File ->Invalidates Cache / Restart 
Solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing this build error after setting a custom style in a manifest file.

> android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

to

> android:theme="@style/TransparentBackgroundApp"

Answer (score 0):

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...
Then Sync Project with Gradle Files