# Android studio 'Error running 'app': Default Activity not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't understand why the error not disappeared

I was thinking it is error from `Manifest.xml` because it show after i adjust manifest file
but i can't find what was my mistake
can you teach me?

[image]

Comment: try one more time compiling it may be some temp emulator related error. If you get some crash then add error logs here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...
```

Comment: i was try to it but after i do that it didnt work... same problem show to me

Comment: try this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640863/android-studio-3-2-default-activity-not-found